# Fulfillment with "location_id" in latest 2023 -01 API

Tags: api, shopify, shopify-api, fulfillment

"Create a new Fulfillment API" available in API version 2022 - 04,
using this API we create the fulfillment with "location_id" now Shopify removed this API endpoint on 2022-07 API,

Please mention which API call was used to create the fulfillment order using "location_id" in the latest 2023 -01 API.

Comment: AFAIK location_id is still there: https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2023-01/resources/fulfillment#create-2021-01

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Shopify doesn't mention the "location_id" param in "Creates a fulfillment for one or many fulfillment orders" API . They only mentioned api_version, line_items_by_fulfillment_order, notify_customer..etc @TwistedOwl

Comment: I am a bit confused about what are you referring to. Can you share any link or reproducible example and include it in your question?